# Clang issues when installing the igraph R package on Mac OS

Tags: r, macos, clang, igraph

I'm trying to install the [pagoda2](https://github.com/hms-dbmi/pagoda2) R package on my Mac.

Did the:

```
brew update
brew install cmake boost eigen gsl curl openssl wget
```

requirements.

Then downloaded and installed the `clang4-r.pkg` package.

Then installed gfortran for Mac.

And then in the inside `R` part, in the:

```
install_github("igraph/rigraph")
```

it fails with this error:

```
* installing *source* package ‘igraph’ ...
checking for gcc... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in `/private/var/folders/t1/t8mvpqx15t50z60z7nqt18y40000gn/T/RtmpNhyp5H/devtools65d816247573/igraph-rigraph-057cc9d':
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘igraph’
```

I tried editing my .R/Makevars file to the following:

```
# The following statements are required to use the clang4 binary
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib
CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include


#CC=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang
CC=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
#CXX=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang++
CXX=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
#CXX1X=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang++
CXX1X=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
#CXX98=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang++
CXX98=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang
#CXX11=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang++
CXX11=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang
#CXX14=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang++
CXX14=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang
#CXX98=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang
CXX98=/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang
#LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/clang4/lib
# End clang4 inclusion statements
```

But still same error message.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you read this? : https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools/

Comment: No, thanks for referring me to this. My R was actually not 3.5, but I downloaded the lates 3.5.1 release. Notwithstanding, the error persists and I'm not sure I understand what to do with the information on that page. Did you mean anything specific there?

Comment: clang6 is the version used for compiling packages with current MacOS fork of R.

Comment: I reinstalled R-3.5.1, clang6, and gfortran-6.1, but I'm still getting the same error when trying to installed igraph.

Comment: With the same Makevars file?